# There is com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:8.1.0?

Tags: android

I need to compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:8.1.0 into my project because I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads version 8.1.0. But I can't sync gradle

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:8.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do this, just keep the version you are using and move this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

To the very end of your application Gradle file and try again